# C# Winform app display only on secondary monitor

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm trying to display a winforms C# app on a secondary monitor fullscreen without having to use extended desktop. e.g. just force display output on the secondary monitor. Is there anyway this can be accomplished? I can't seem to find a way to do it. Thank you for your help!

UPDATE: Here is the code of the current method I use to get the monitor on the secondary or chosen display with extended desktop. But the goal is not to have to use extended desktop configuration.

```
private void show0nMonitor(int showOnMonitor)
{
    Screen[] sc;
    sc = Screen.AllScreens;
    if (showOnMonitor >= sc.Length)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Monitor Not Found. Defaulting to Monitor 1",
        "Error",
        MessageBoxButtons.OK,
        MessageBoxIcon.Error,
        MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1);
        showOnMonitor = 0;
    }

    this.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
    this.Location = new Point(sc[showOnMonitor].Bounds.Left,sc[showOnMonitor].Bounds.Top);
    this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
    this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
}
```

UPDATE 2:

Would it be possible to render the app using something like DirectX to display the app on the second output? Using the image link below below using IDXGIoutput 2 on a system? C++ and DirectX is way beyond my skills though any input if that is even possible?

[IDXGIoutput image MSFT](https://i-msdn.sec.s-msft.com/dynimg/IC412503.png)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe seems stupid code but based on you demand we can't use my sent code but try this :

```
Screen[] sc;
sc = Screen.AllScreens;
this.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
this.Location = new Point(sc[sc.Length-1].Bounds.Right - sc[sc.Length-1].Bounds.Width, sc[sc.Length-1].Bounds.Top);
this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
this.Size = sc[sc.Length - 1].Bounds.Size;
```

Comment: Thanks for the response!, I tried this code and the app still will not show when extended mode is turned off, which is the goal.

Comment: What is "extended mode"

Comment: It is when the desktop is extended over two displays in Windows. http://www.windowscentral.com/how-connect-and-set-multiple-monitors-windows-10#switch

Comment: @Yashar, I tried your updated code and it works great when the desktop is set to extended mode, but I'm trying to display the app on the second monitor when the mode is set to only display on monitor 1. Also code is never stupid as long as it works ;).

Comment: Thank you @jones.but I already tested this on extended display and result was ok.but I can't get your point and your purpose

Comment: I'm sorry I guess I wasn't clear enough. My goal is to have two monitors attached to the system with windows desktop only displaying on one display and the app running on the other screen. E.g. Windows set to display only on monitor 1 and when the program runs it displays on monitor 2. Hope that explains it a little better. Thank you for your help with this, it's killing me trying to figure it out.